# Order posts by custom field and if custom field is empty return remaining posts

Tags: custom-field, loop, query-posts

I have an archive page ordered by a numeric value in a custom field.  This returns the ordered posts correctly, but does not display posts that don't have a custom field.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
query_posts("paged=$paged&cat=7&posts_per_page=24&meta_key=custom_order&orderby=meta_value_num&order=ASC");
```

What is the best way to return the ordered posts correctly, followed by any posts that do not have a custom field value associated with them?

**Edit**: Just to elaborate -- The final result that I want to accomplish is a category archive page that has specific posts show up first, followed by the rest.  Pretty much like sticky posts, but only for a specific category archive.

**Edit Two**: I am trying Jessica's suggestion, and I think we're almost there.

The problem is that now if I set to `order=ASC` then all of the posts that have the custom field filled, show up after the posts that don't have a value associated.  If I set `order=DESC` then the posts that have a custom field value are returned first, but in reverse.  So, it would appear 4, 3, 2, 1, and then the rest of the posts with no value associated.  How can I correct the order, so it shows 1, 2, 3, 4, and then the rest of the posts with no value in the `custom_order` field?

I have added the following to my functions.php:

```
function wpse_55791_custom_order($clauses)
{
    global $wp_query;

    // check for order by custom_order
    if ($wp_query->get('meta_key') == 'custom_order' && $wp_query->get('orderby') == 'meta_value_num')
    {
        // change the inner join to a left outer join, 
        // and change the where so it is applied to the join, not the results of the query
        $clauses['join'] = str_replace('INNER JOIN', 'LEFT OUTER JOIN', $clauses['join']).$clauses['where'];
        $clauses['where'] = '';
    }
    return $clauses;
}
add_filter('get_meta_sql', 'wpse_55791_custom_order', 10, 1);
function wpse_55791_custom_orderby($orderby)
{
    global $wp_query;

    // check for order by custom_order
    if ($wp_query->get('meta_key') == 'custom_order' && $wp_query->get('orderby') == 'meta_value_num')
    {
        $orderby = "{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value='', ".$orderby;
    }
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'wpse_55791_custom_orderby', 10, 1);
```

Comment: If someone is interested in a pure SQL look at this issue, I have opened this Question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714365/sql-ordering-results-from-joined-table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you specify a meta_key, `query_posts()` does an INNER JOIN between the wp_posts and wp_postmeta table. That means that any posts that don't have any meta value for the key you specified won't ever be returned in that query.

In order to do what you need, you should use the same query you posted in your question, but change `orderby=meta_value` to `orderby=meta_value_num`. Then you can filter 'get_meta_sql' to make the join return all posts. Add the following to your functions.php:

```
<?php
function wpse_55791_custom_order($clauses)
{
    global $wp_query;

    // check for order by custom_order
    if ($wp_query->get('meta_key') == 'custom_order' && $wp_query->get('orderby') == 'meta_value_num')
    {
        // change the inner join to a left join, 
        // and change the where so it is applied to the join, not the results of the query
        $clauses['join'] = str_replace('INNER JOIN', 'LEFT JOIN', $clauses['join']).$clauses['where'];
        $clauses['where'] = '';
    }
    return $clauses;
}
add_filter('get_meta_sql', 'wpse_55791_custom_order', 10, 1);
?>
```

EDIT: To fix the ordering, try adding this along with the above:

```
<?php
function wpse_55791_custom_orderby($orderby)
{
    global $wp_query, $wpdb;

    // check for order by custom_order
    if ($wp_query->get('meta_key') == 'custom_order' && $wp_query->get('orderby') == 'meta_value_num')
    {
        $orderby = "{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value='', ".$orderby;
    }
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'wpse_55791_custom_orderby', 10, 1);
?>
```

EDIT TWO - 2 loops:

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$ordered_posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'cat' => 7,
    'posts_per_page' => 24,
    'meta_key' => 'custom_order',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
));

$unordered = new WP_Query(array(
    'cat' => 7,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 24 - $ordered_posts->post_count,
));

if ($ordered_posts->have_posts()) :
    while ($ordered_posts->have_posts()) : $ordered_posts->the_post();
    // loop 1
    endwhile;
endif;

if ($unordered_posts->have_posts()) :
    while ($unordered_posts->have_posts()) : $unordered_posts->the_post();
    // loop 2
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Note that if you think there are ever going to be more than 24 ordered posts, the paged variable will be wrong for the unordered posts; you might need to set a global variable to keep track of how many ordered / unordered posts have been displayed so far and use that to calculate separate `$paged` values for each type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jessica, but that still results in the same problem.  If the posts don't have a value in the `custom_order` field then they aren't displayed at ll.

Comment: @Ryan I see, I think I read the original question too quickly. Is there some reason why you don't want to use two loops? If that'd work for you, I can post some code..

Comment: I am not against using multiple loops, but I was just hoping to find a way to do it all within one.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Ryan this won't be possible using the regular `query_posts()` function. I updated my answer with another possible solution.

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing this up!  I'll be giving it a shot tomorrow, and will report back.

Comment: I think I am almost there. I have made an edit above that shows what I am currently using, and what the problem is. Essentially, all of the posts without values in `custom_order` show up first, followed by those with the value associated.  If I set `order=DESC` then the posts with a value associated show up first, but in descending order (4,3,2,1). How can I get those posts to show up first, and in correct ASC order? Thanks so much for your help, I really do appreciate it, and I've definitely learned a lot already!

Comment: @Ryan - sounds like you'll have to alter the orderby clause as well. you can order on multiple columns, probably do something like sort on meta_value is not null to put those at the front. dba stackexchange may be a good place to ask for help on that.

Comment: @Ryan I updated my answer and added a second function for filtering the orderby. Let us know if it works. :)

Comment: @jessica - I tried adding the additional function to `functions.php` but now my category-x archive isn't returning any posts. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ryan at the top of your template, can you put `global $wp_query; echo $wp_query->request;` and then [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) the results?

Comment: @jessica - Sure thing! http://pastebin.com/gMWicpR0

Comment: @Ryan it doesn't appear to be passing through any of the filters now.. did the query_posts() call change for some reason?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3897/discussion-between-ryan-and-jessica)

Comment: Back to this again... Just for comparison, how would it be done using two loops?

Comment: @Ryan just updated my answer with some code.

Comment: @jessica - I seriously can't thank you enough for all of your help.  I appreciate your time, and your knowledge!

Comment: @Ryan -- no problem, did it work?

Comment: @jessica - I've actually been playing with both - The two loops solution seems to be working right now.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the post IDs in an array and then query for all posts excluding  those IDs:

```
$post_ids = array();
foreach( $wp_query->posts as $post ):
    $post_ids[] = $post->ID;
endforeach;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__not_in' => $post_ids
);
$remaining = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: You'll end up doing two queries, sorting them in PHP, and returning (possibly) way more posts than you actually want.  You'll also probably break pagination.  This seems like a very fragile approach for both performance and maintenance.

Comment: @Evan either I misunderstand the question, or you misunderstand my answer.

Comment: Evan, what would you recommend doing instead? I'm going to try this solution for the time being and see if I can get it working.  Thanks both!

Comment: @Ryan - the important question here is the context within this will be used- if you want it to work like a normal category page with pagination then this solution won't work for you, you'll have to filter the individual query components and alter the SQL directly.

Comment: @Milo - Thanks! I updated the original question with some more information about the final goal.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this in a very easy way, using an array for the ordering, as below:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
                    'orderby' => array(
                        'meta_key' => 'meta_key', /* your meta key here */
                        'meta_value' => 'meta_value_num',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                    )
            ));
```

That should fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good workaround even if I dont like it at all. It's again the limitation of the query api of wordpress. I loved to do it with mysql in the old ages.. but messing with WP is sometimes..you know

```
//get only ordered posts
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'supporters',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'wpcf-sorting'
);
$cat_posts = new WP_Query($args);

//collect ordered post ids
$post_ids = array();
foreach( $cat_posts->posts as $post ):
    $post_ids[] = $post->ID;
endforeach;


//get only unordered posts
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'supporters',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__not_in' => $post_ids
);
$cat_posts_unordered = new WP_Query($args);


if ($cat_posts->have_posts() || $cat_posts_unordered->have_posts()) {   
    while ($cat_posts->have_posts()) {
        $cat_posts->the_post();

        get_template_part( 'content-supporters', get_post_format());
    }
    while ($cat_posts_unordered->have_posts()) {
        $cat_posts_unordered->the_post();

        get_template_part( 'content-supporters', get_post_format());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please just explain what your code is doing instead of ranting about the Query limitations you think WP has.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of easiness and as my solution is for the admin-panel it doesn't focus on efficiency. What I did is loading all posts and then sorting it using php.

```
function MY_PLUGIN_get_ordered_pages_by_cat_id($cat_id) {
    $all_pages = get_posts(
                array(
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'cat' => $cat_id,
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                )
            );

    $pages      = [];
    $page_len   = count($all_pages);
    foreach($all_pages as $page):
        $positon        = @get_post_meta($cat_id, '_page_position', true);
        $a_pos          = !empty($positon) ? $positon : $page_len++;
        $pages[$a_pos]  = $page;
    endforeach;
    sort($pages);
    return $pages;
}
```

Maybe its helpful to someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if the question is very old, it seems not to be answered yet (see Edit 2 in the above question).
I wasn't happy with the previous solutions so I used nested meta queries to solve the problem.

```
    function sort_posts_by_custom_field( $query ) {
        $query->set('meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            'custom_field_clause' => array(
                'key' => 'custom_field',
                'value' => '0',
                'compare' => '>',
                'type' => 'DECIMAL'
            ),
            'no_custom_field_clause' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'custom_field',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'custom_field',
                    'value' => null,
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            )
        ));
        $query->set('orderby', array('custom_field_clause' => 'ASC'));
        return $query;
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sort_posts_by_custom_field');
```

In Words: Before querying posts, query those posts, that have custom_field set and those, that don't have custom_field set (or set to null). (Query both, elsewise one of them will be ignored.) Then sort by custom_field ascending.